# What does mean "Android Key Hash" in "Native Android App" section in FB application settings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coronasdk

I write with Corona SDK a mobile application that integrates with Facebook. So I created a Facebook application that App ID I use for integration.

In login session from mobile device, I received a error with response "android key ....". The solution for the problem was to set a "Android Key Hash" in "Native Android App" of the application. But I don't understand exactly what does mean "Android Key Hash" and what I did. Can somebody pleases explain me about?

Could I still receive the same error if  I run an application on other device or this "Android Key Hash" is unique for all my application's users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wont get an error provided you use the correct hash key. You can generate one by using this command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

If you are getting an error at that point try using a non debug keystore to sign and/or take a look at this post from the Corona SDK forums; http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/03/20/facebook-and-android-key-hash